# When given a non-multiple of $3$, $k$, is it possible construct $m<k$ with these conditions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, diophantine-equations, conjectures, collatz-conjecture

This is another Collatz-related problem about trying to represent a number in a certain form. As is usually the case with the Collatz conjecture, this is probably not useful. My question is :

> Can you construct $m,k, n \in \Bbb{Z^+}$ such that:
>   $$\frac{2^n k -\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 2^{n-1-i} \times 3^i}{3^n}= m<k$$

As I have said, this has some link to the Collatz conjecture as you may be able to tell. Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum on the left hand side can be simplified given that
$$a^n-b^n=(a-b)\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a^ib^{n-1-i}.$$
So the left hand side becomes
$$\frac{2^nk-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}2^{n-1-i}\times3^i}{3^n}
=\frac{2^nk-(3^n-2^n)}{3^n}
=2^n\frac{k+1}{3^n}-1.$$
This is an integer if and only if $k+1$ is a multiple of $3^n$, say $k=c3^n-1$. In this case we have
$$m=c2^n-1<c3^n-1=k.$$

Comment: Any idea how to approach when considering $a \geq n$?

Comment: Ah, my mistake. It is the former, I have corrected it.

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote?

Comment: I accidentally downvoted, I apologise, can you edit your question to unlock my vote?

Comment: Edited, and thank you. I see your question has changed. I don't understand it anymore. If you have a new question, please ask a new question.

Comment: I did not mean to make it unclear.